# ROS 2 time handling

Tags: ros, ros2, rclcpp, ardent, time

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In ROS 1 my node has code like this in a subscribed message callback:

```
ros::Time now = ros::Time::now();
ros::Duration frameSkip = ros::Duration(m_frameSyncMs/1000.0);

// Proceed if time interval has elapsed or if clock has gone backwards
if (m_previousTimeStamp + frameSkip > now)
// etc...
```

Basically, when `m_frameSyncMs` is 100 ms with the topic being a camera feed at 30 fps, just pick out every third frame or so. This works quite happily.

Now, for ROS 2 there no longer is a `Time::now()`, and looking at various web pages there might be a node clock, or there might be an `rcl_get_time_point_now()` but shouldn't that also take the result of `rcl_get_default_ros_time()`?

What is the best way to do this? Furthermore, where is the best place to learn about the latest ROS 2 developments; GitHub and Discord, for instance seem a bit too light on information, and reading the source might work, but the next beta may very well invalidate everything. Finally is there a `ros2bag` or equivalent for recording and playing back runs?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287946/ros-2-time-handling/) by [KenYN](https://answers.ros.org/users/25651/kenyn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 541 on 2018-04-09

Post score: 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want the equivalent "ROS Time" as in ROS 1, e.g. might return wall clock time or simulated time (see https://wiki.ros.org/Clock#Using_Simulation_Time_from_the_.2BAC8-clock_Topic), then you need to call `now()` on a Node, see:

http://docs.ros2.org/ardent/api/rclcpp/classrclcpp_1_1_node.html#af706b231620f1c120b7ccd738ec31867

The reason you need to get "now" from a node in ROS 2 is because unlike ROS 1, there's no global node singleton and the ROS time clock requires things like parameters and topics to implement sim time. So in ROS 2 you need to have a node to use ROS time.

If you only ever care about real time (no simulated time), then I suggest either using a custom made `rclcpp::Clock`, which defaults to "System time":

http://docs.ros2.org/ardent/api/rclcpp/classrclcpp_1_1_clock.html#abe5646eb46910ea5bda2486d082a31ab

Or give it an argument of `RCL_STEADY_TIME` to get monotonically increasing time.

You can also just use `std::chrono::system_clock` or `std::chrono::steady_clock` if you're not using ROS time:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2018-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 10

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KenYN](https://answers.ros.org/users/25651/kenyn/) on 2018-04-09**:
Thanks for the quick reply! That's solved my immediate problem.

**Comment by [bbus](https://answers.ros.org/users/52100/bbus/) on 2020-02-26**:
Has any of this changed in the past two years? (I'm on Eloquent on Ubuntu 18.04.)
I found Intel's ros2 realsense source code, and have been using it as a bit of an example of how I might port to ros2.
[see here](https://github.com/intel/ros2_intel_realsense/blob/master/realsense_ros2_camera/src/realsense_camera_node.cpp)
They create a `rclcpp::Clock` instance, then in the initializer list set that clock instance to `RCL_ROS_TIME`. I am understanding what they essentially did is take your second suggestion and substituted out "System time" for "ROS time". Is my understanding correct?

I'm trying to understand what the difference would be between doing something like what Intel did, versus using the Node `now()` method as in your first suggestion.

Thanks!

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2020-02-28**:
The approach in the realsense driver linked above does not associate a Time Source with the clock (which the node does for you) and as such it will never switch to simulated time. As this is a sensor driver that's likely not a use case that has come up.  Note that you can also use `get_clock()` from the node and call `now()` on the initialized clock too.

**Comment by [bbus](https://answers.ros.org/users/52100/bbus/) on 2020-02-28**:
Ok, so calling rclcpp::init generates a link to the "time source" in the backend code? Is there a way for me to link the ros time source manually?

Problem I'm having is that I'm attempting to port a ROS1 project that creates a nodehandle inside a library, and that nodehandle is used to create a timer inside the library. But, that library isn't a node itself. Maybe I've misunderstood other code, but I don't think we can have a ros2 nodehandle spawned out of the blue, without it being tied to an actual node, which is what the project devs originally did. I don't want to have to pass a nodehandle 3 layers into this library for two timers that can be paused with simulation time. I was attempting to create my own rclcpp::GenericTimer with this clock that I thought would be linked to simulation time by creating it with RCL_ROS_TIME, as Intel did.

Maybe at this point I should start a new question. I don't feel like I'm being very clear.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2020-02-28**:
No the `init` does not do anything with a `TimeSource` that's only done by the `Node` initialization. In ROS 1 there was global state going on under the hood, but we've removed that in ROS 2. So you do need a Node to get a properly initialized clock. The clock cannot listen for the simulated time without a `Node` instance, (which is built into the `Node` so you don't have to do it yourself.)

**Comment by [bbus](https://answers.ros.org/users/52100/bbus/) on 2020-02-28**:
I understand I don't have to do it myself, but is it technically possible to do myself?

Also, from reading the "Clock and Time" design article (https://design.ros2.org/articles/clock_and_time.html) I suspected that a randomly spawned clock, using `rclcpp::Clock my_clock(RCL_ROS_TIME)`, in a source code file that isn't a node, would search for the `/clock` topic and use that, hence using the simulation time if I publish sim time to `/clock` somewhere else. From what you are saying, it sounds like this isn't the case, but that `my_clock` spawned in this manner does not look for/at `/clock` for knowledge of time. If this is correct, then great, I'm glad to be finally understanding. And that makes me wonder now, that would mean only Nodes know of topics, not instances of object types in rclcpp. I feel like I'm being very dense, and I apologize for that. I appreciate your patience and explanations.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2020-02-28**:
You're correct that only `Nodes` know about topics. The `Clock` object is just an object with no communication. It cannot "search for the `/clock` topic".

The default clock is just a clock object that does not know about any time source. If you attach a `TimeSource` such as our default one which listens to `/clock` and reads the `use_sim_time` parameter it will get updated based on that `TimeSource` if it's set to use `RCL_ROS_TIME` If it's a different type the `TimeSource` won't affect it.

**Comment by [doisyg](https://answers.ros.org/users/25266/doisyg/) on 2021-02-03**:
Jumping in. As I understand with this answer that the default clock of a node listens to the */clock* topic  when *use_sim_time* is true, when is this clock updated?  It seems that it would be frozen when any callback on the node is being served ? Which is a different behavior than when *use_sim_time* is false (the node clock being system time, it would node be frozen inside a callback)